# Webgrid in div based format

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

I have the following code :-

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="comment-box">
        <div class="comment-head">
            <div class="comment-name">
                @item.FromUser
            </div>
            <div class="comment-date">
                @item.DaysAgo
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="comment-content">
            @item.Message
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

I want to show this by `webgrid`. But problem is `webgrid` shows the data in columns, how to do it in `div` structure.

This is my new code for using webgrid :-

```
@{ 
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model); 
}
<div>
   @grid.GetHtml()
</div>
```

Comment: Show tabular structured data in `table`. If you need to show in `div` you need to write a custom column render. Why you need div based? Look jQGrid and check will it help you

Comment: @Murali Coz Comment Box is pre-defined with Styles which are div based.

Comment: Then only that particular column can be custom formatted like `<td><div>..</div></td>`. check out jQGrid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following thing worked for me :-

```
@{ 
        var grid = new WebGrid(Model); 
 }
    <div>
        @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "table-comment",
        columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column("", "", @<text><div class="comment-box">
        <div class="comment-head">
            <div class="comment-name">
                @item.FromUser
            </div>
            <div class="comment-date">
                @item.DaysAgo
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="comment-content">
            @item.Message
        </div>
    </div></text>)))

    </div>
```